# How to add (write a review) / (rate this app) in my app on iOS 7

Tags: ios, uiwebview, cocos2d-iphone, ios7, popup

I know that there are other answers on this forum for adding this feature to my app but none of the answers deal with iOS 7. I have heard that (iRate) is one of the better options for this but is that still the best option for iOS 7? Any help would be appreciated!! P.S I am using cocos2d in my app.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you aren't aware of the iTunes Link Maker, it'll come in handy for linking to your app. [link maker](https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/us/)

Answer (score 1):

I use Appirater (https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater).  Even if you don't want to remind your users it has a call to rate your app and it presents within your app.

Comment: Do you know if the direct call to rate your app goes to the reviews section for your app in the app store or does it just go to the details section?